# Format of date time column is changing when change the query fro6m inner join to left join

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime

I have used below query to bind to my gridview. In gridview there are two hidden fields.

```
 sql = "SELECT a.Submission_id ,a.Name,a.Submitted_time  as Normal_submitted_time," +
                    "b.Subject,b.Submitted_time  AS Final_submitted_time FROM a " +
                    " JOIN b ON a.Submission_id = b.Submission_id ";

  <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldNormalSubmittedTime" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Normal_submitted_time") %>'/> 
                       <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFielFinalSubmittedTime" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Final_submitted_time ") %>'/> 

string HiddenFieldNormalSubmittedTime = Convert.ToString(((HiddenField)gvrow.FindControl("HiddenFieldNormalSubmittedTime")).Value);
string HiddenFieldFinalSubmittedTime = Convert.ToString(((HiddenField)gvrow.FindControl("HiddenFielFinalSubmittedTime")).Value);
```

Value of HiddenFieldNormalSubmittedTime is getting as

> 12-06-2020 10:20:51 PM

And value of HiddenFieldFinalSubmittedTime  =

> 17-06-2020 12:30:58 PM

But when changing the same query to LEFT JOIN

```
    sql = "SELECT a.Submission_id ,a.Name,a.Submitted_time  as Normal_submitted_time," +
                    "b.Subject,b.Submitted_time  AS Final_submitted_time FROM a " +
                    " JOIN b ON a.Submission_id = b.Submission_id ";
```

the format of HiddenFieldFinalSubmittedTime  is changes to

> 06/17/2020 13:12:55

HiddenFieldNormalSubmittedTime  is remain as same.
What is the reason for it?
Can I make it to a common format (12-06-2020 10:20:51 PM) while binding eval to hiddenfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the format in your SQL query as

```
FORMAT (a.Submitted_time, 'dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Now when bounding this values to a column,  DataFormatString is not working.     <asp:BoundField DataField="Final_submitted_time " HeaderText="Time" DataFormatString="{0:t}"
                                    ReadOnly="True"  >  </asp:BoundField>   It shows full date with time

Comment: just change the dataformatsetting   dataformatstring ="{dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss}"

Comment: I only want to show the timepart from it. ex  10:20 PM

Comment: Then just use HH:mm